# Store a list of numbers returned by a query into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'd like to store the `Id`s returned by a query like so into a variable:

```
SELECT FooId FROM Bar; -- FooId is of type int
```

So that I may later say something like:

```
DELETE FROM Foo WHERE Id IN @TheFooIdsIGotFromThePreviousQueryAbove;
```

How do I do that? Specifically, what datatype must I declare such a list variable to be of?

Notice that I could have simply done:

```
DELETE FROM Foo WHERE Id IN (SELECT FooId FROM Bar);
```

But I don't can't do that for reasons that will simply complicate the question.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: use `temp table` or `table variable` to store the `Id`

Comment: You can use OUTPUT Clause but I am not sure if it is present in mysql. Linkhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . and can use table variable .

Comment: @ch2019 output clause cannot help here, and the question is not about mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `temp table` or `table variable` to store the Id

```
-- declare table variable
declare @IDS table (Id int)

-- insert into the table variable
insert into @IDS (Id) SELECT FooId FROM Bar

-- join the table variable to the table you want to delete
DELETE d
FROM   Foo d
       INNER JOIN @IDS i ON d.Id = i.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also use Temp Tables

```
SELECT FooId AS ID INTO #tmp_bar FROM Bar 

--#tmp_bar can be used as a normal table
SELECT ID FROM #tmp_bar
```